# What can I do to ignore the domain on a redirect request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 domains, one is for development, another for QA and another for production.
Let's say:

- dev-domain.com
- qa-domain.com
- prod-domain.com

And I want to send the user to another location after he submits an email:

`window.location.href = 'confirmation.html';`

So, what I want to avoid doing on every environment:

`window.location.href = 'dev-domain.com/confirmation.html';` or `window.location.href = 'qa-domain.com/confirmation.html';`, and only doing something like:

`window.location.href = '(Test-Domain)/confirmation.html';`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `window.location.hostname + '/confirmation.html'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location` has several properties, like host, protocol, port, etc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

You can change just the path of the Location object:

```
window.location.pathname = '/confirmation.html';
```

Answer (score 2):

`file_name.html` should be sufficient because it's relative path. Do you need to implement absolute paths?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as [Oluwafemi Sule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5189811/oluwafemi-sule)  pointed out the `window.location.hostname` property returns the name of the internet host (of the current page).

So you can use:
`window.location.href = window.location.hostname + '/confirmation.html';`